# Gravitational redshift inside tunnel that goes to the center (where the light comes from) of massive body of radius $R$ a distance $r$ from the center

Tags: general-relativity, redshift, gravitational-redshift

I'd like to know the general formula of the gravitational red shift for light emitted from the center of a massive body of density $\rho$ and radius $R$ where the light is emitted from the center of the massive body up a tunnel and received at a radius $r$ distance from the center, where $r<R$.